# Gmail Add-on Auth Token flow does not complete - redirects to Broken Gdrive page

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am attempting to use the [App Script OAuth](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) library for a GMail add-on. My code is essentially a copy/paste of the Non-Google OAuth configuration example from here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services - which pretty much calls methods from the OAuth library to build a card and initiate auth-flow.

From everything I understand, the auth-flow itself is fully handled by the library - at the end of which, I can access my auth token.

However, in my case, the auth-flow stops after triggering the redirect URL:

```
https://script.google.com/a/macros/workboard.com/<script_id>/usercallback/?success=1&code=&state=.
```

At this point, the auth pop-window has the above URL (with actual values, not placeholders) and a Google drive page with a message saying:

"Sorry, unable to open the file at this time."

I have tried debugging this on my end - as well as searching for answers but to no avail. Would appreciate any pointers to on what the issue might be or what I can do to debug this further.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below-given URL:
Please add "/d/" after domain and remove "/"  after usercallback.

```
https://script.google.com/a/macros/workboard.com/d/<script_id>/usercallback?success=1&code=&state=
```